# Yandex Maps return 403 Forbidden using retrofit

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit, yandex-maps

When I call this link https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=astana on my browser it works, but when I call it using retrofit It gives me 403 Forbidden

My code is

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Settings.YANDEX_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(YandexService.class);

public final static String YANDEX_URL = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x";
```

I call it using this

```
@GET("/")
Call<YandexResponse> getGeoCollection(@Query("format") String format, @Query("geocode") String geocode);
```

and this

```
@Override
public void getMapLocation() {
    Call<YandexResponse> call = dataProvider.yandexSearch("Astana");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YandexResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<YandexResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Alert.showDefaultAlert(baseActivity);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Why it gives to me 403 Forbidden, it doesn't need any authorization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Just paste `/1.x/` from YANDEX_URL to  Service

become this

```
public final static String YANDEX_URL = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru";

@GET("/1.x/")
Call<YandexResponse> getGeoCollection(@Query("format") String format, 
                                      @Query("geocode") String geocode);
```