# 403 Forbidden in Yandex Weather API

Tags: android, api, retrofit, http-status-code-403

I need to create some app. This app shows weather forecast. Google weather API gone. But Yandex have this API.My code right, but with this api i have some problem. In the example write:https://api.weather.yandex.ru/v1/forecast?geoid=213&l10n=true. But this example return 403.https://api.weather.yandex.ru/v1/forecast?geoid=2&lang=ru_RU also return 403.But once it return forecast then it returns 403.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/weather/doc/dg/concepts/about-docpage/ - Yandex weather api documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You use `HttpURLConnection` may be some parameters of header missing (like `content-type` or `encoding`). And probably `HttpURLConnection` should be configured like `setRequestMethod("GET");` or something like that: HTTP Authentication, Proxy, Cookies and so on  (take a look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)).

Comment: I use Retrofit. But I say: code is working. When I try manually enter link(not from code) I have 403 :(

Comment: When i try get forecast from code I have NullPointerException because yandex weather return 403

Comment: Both your links are working, so issue is in connection settings (`content-type`). Do you use `https` not `http`? Or what is `"User-agent"` value?

Comment: I use https. What do you mean:"User-agent"?

Comment: `http` header [has many fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) and they should be configured  properly to access (e.g. `"Content-Type"`).

Comment: and take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885802/yandex-maps-return-403-forbidden-using-retrofit) question.